# Android camera being landscaped in some devices

Tags: android, view, camera, portrait

Im new to Android and I tried a tutorial for camera API. The tutorial works fine. When I use HTC desire I can see the camera view in both portrait and landscape, but when I use Samsung Galaxy I get a the camera view only in a landscaped view. I tried the following code to rotate the camera view as well..

```
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();                        
        parameters.setRotation(90);
```

then the camera doesn't work as expected. (screen splits into 4 and not clear).
Does anyone have an idea for this issue ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung camera app will work as Samsung intended it to. Unfortunately, you won't be able to change another vendor's app behavior unless it was made to accept such changes.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Samsung. It should work as the API says it will.